# How to get the name of the Coroutine which was launched with CoroutineName field

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am launching a `Coroutine` with field `CoroutineName` like this

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        launch(CoroutineName("newName")) {
            println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        }
    }
}
```

when I print the current thread name, I am not getting `main newName` as the name, Instead I will get only `main` as the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only see coroutine name if debug mode is turned on. Otherwise only thread name is shown.

You can turn on debug with JVM option `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug`

If you want more details you can find it on [this link](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-d-e-b-u-g_-p-r-o-p-e-r-t-y_-n-a-m-e.html)